# can we extract only year in the string "04.07.2019 16:56:21" without using for loop?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to extract the year from a date and time string something like "04.07.2019 16:56:21". Can I extract only year without using for loop in batch script?

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer this method when setting variables for log entries:

```
@echo off

set "year=%DATE:~-4%"

echo %year%

pause
```

To get it out of your specific string:

```
@echo off

set "string=04.07.2019 16:56:21"
set "year=%string:~6,4%"

echo %year%

pause
```

Just keep in mind that %DATE% can be location specific so you can tinker with it a little if necessary. The second example can pull your date string from wherever you want, it just skips six characters and displays the next four.

Reference: [variable substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)